# jQuery UI resizable grid with spaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the "resizable" widget of jQuery UI to add a resize functionality to an element.

With the "grid" option, the element can be resized based on a given grid, say 100/80. I want the grid cells to be spaced (say 5) so I made the actual grid 105/85.

I drew the grid in a "canvas" element so that it is easier to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/584794/

```
$box.resizable({
    handles: "all",
    grid: [105, 85]
});
```

Resizing from the right/bottom sides works well but when resizing from the top/left sides, it forces the minimum box size to 105x85.

I understand that within the grid, it tries to set the minimum dimension to a grid cell but since the right/bottom sides work how I need them to, I am looking to have the same behavior for top/left as well.

I am trying to edit the jQuery UI code to make this change so that I don't have to code a complete new resizable functionality on my own.

I searched through the source code of the resizable widget but I cannot locate the code that forces the minimum dimensions on the top/left resize. I am hoping that someone with more experience in working with the jQuery UI code can point me in the right direction.

The source code of the resizable widget can be previewed here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/resizable.js

Or it can be downloaded from https://jqueryui.com > "Custom download" and selecting only "Resizable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the source code of the resizable widget of jQuery UI, I have managed to find the code that makes the left and top resizing be different.

The fix is simple and requires only disabling 2 lines of code:

```
$.ui.plugin.add( "resizable", "grid", {

    resize: function() {
        ...
        } else {
            if ( newHeight - gridY <= 0 || newWidth - gridX <= 0 ) {
                outerDimensions = that._getPaddingPlusBorderDimensions( this );
            }

            if ( newHeight - gridY > 0 ) {
                that.size.height = newHeight;
                that.position.top = op.top - oy;
            } else {
                // newHeight = gridY - outerDimensions.height;
                that.size.height = newHeight;
                that.position.top = op.top + os.height - newHeight;
            }
            if ( newWidth - gridX > 0 ) {
                that.size.width = newWidth;
                that.position.left = op.left - ox;
            } else {
                // newWidth = gridX - outerDimensions.width;
                that.size.width = newWidth;
                that.position.left = op.left + os.width - newWidth;
            }
        }
    }

}
```